# Is there any evidence that birds use thermal currents generated from highways to glide?

Tags: birds, thermals

I am looking for an article on the subject matter of birds using thermal currents generated from highways to glide. I know I have seen and read about this before but cannot find any research on the subject matter.

Comment: Just  a random thought.  Birds *do* use thermal currents to glide.  And highways--especially *some* highways, namely blacktop highways-- undoubtedly *do* generate significant thermal currents.  So, it seems the most logical hypothesis would be "yes", and that a "no" hypothesis should not be entertained without some rather compelling proof.  So, with that in mind-- could the question possibly be refined?  For example, do you possibly want to ask whether there is *evidence* of birds using thermals generated from highways to glide?

Comment: I don't see how this is related to Aviation. I think it would be better suited for [Biology.SE](https://biology.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks you @quietflyer. the question should be, 'is there evidence...'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally don't get "walls" of rising air from a narrow strip heat source like a highway. Thermals tend to come from single sources, parking lots, dry fields, etc.

You do get a kind of "highway in the sky" on certain days with the right convective conditions, where consistent thermal sources, and a smooth flow of the moving airmass, cause thermals that tend to line up in rows downwind of their sources.

Where the thermals are topping out in cumulous clouds, soaring pilots call them "cloud streets". In a glider you can fly along a street, climbing in thermals and descending between them, without really having to turn in the thermals if the conditions are strong enough.

A bird travelling in a particular direction could also exploit a cloud street if the direction was where they wanted to go. But generally birds that are out thermalling are either hunting or just playing around. Glider pilots fly with them quite a lot.

Comment: Re " But generally birds that are out thermalling are either hunting or just playing around." -- except during migration season!  Over one hundred thousand hawks typically pass by in *one day* during the peak of the fall migration season at one flat-land count station in south Texas... sometimes flying near cloud base and disappearing at times *into* the bottoms of the clouds...   Plus, consider also that on a windy day, a thermalling hawk has to spend a fair amount of time gliding back into the wind just to "stay local", and cloud streets would seem ideal for that too--

Comment: Yeah good point.

Comment: You see gulls ridge soaring all day in front of any office building when the wind is going. I'll bet geese take advantage of ridge lift in the Appalachians when migrating south.